# need an android service to run always

Tags: android, service

I have been searching a lot but I still cant figure a solution for this

I have a service with return Start_Sticky in onStartCommand, and it will start itself in onDestroy method of service. I though this would be enough because my service would be either stopped from user so then onDestroy method would be called. or stopped by android, then because of Start_Sticky, android would recreate it after killing it, but android doesn't start my service after killing it.

so I used AlarmManager class to register a broadcast receiver and then start my service in onReceive method, but it seems after phone going to sleep mode, onReceive method wont get called again. I even tried using wakeLock

anyway the question is how to make the service run always or recreate itself after stoping, like telegram or instagram services

this is my service:

```
public final class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //some stuff

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 12345, ii, 0);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1 * 60 * 1000, pi);
        else
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1*60*1000, pi);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onDestroy() {
        startService(new Intent(ACTION_MAIN).setClass(context, MyService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and here's my receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        //WakeLocker.acquire(context);

        context.startService(new Intent(ACTION_MAIN).setClass(context, MyService.class));

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            AlarmManager am2 =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, i, 0);
            am2.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1*60*1000, pi);
        }
        else
        {
            AlarmManager am2 =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, i, 0);
            am2.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1*60*1000, pi);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
ok i have got a simpler question
why this simple service doesn't get recreated after android killing it ? 
i start the service using startService in activity but after about 20 min my service gets disappear in the running tasks... why is that ?

```
public class NotificationsService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused by what you are trying to do here. You should have a class that is not listed that sets up the alarmManager and kicks off the alarm, the MyReciever Class will pick this up and start the service. I dont understand why the MyReciever class and Service Class have the AlarmManager in them? You should also not be using the same ID for the two different PendingIntents - I would remove the AlarmManager from MyService altogether, unless I am missing something in your question

Comment: yes you are missing something... since android kitkat setRepeating method of alarmmanager is inexact so im handling it by setting another alarm in onReceive method to simulate setRepeating. and as you see there is a if so i do not have two pending intent with similar ids

Comment: @CommonsWare i have been searching alot and i didnt get any answer, i though maybe u can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No service in android can run indefinitely(PERSISTENT) accept for system services.

You can only make the service return START_STICKY.Acquiring wake lock is not a good idea because it will drain users battery.

Even if the service gets killed it will be restarted by the system.

You can implement a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver so as to start the service when the device is booted.

Comment: thanks for your reply. service does not get restarted by system, i mentioned it in my question

Comment: It's weird...but for me the system always restarts the service...can u remove start service from on destroy and try

Comment: yes im gonna try that, but what should I do if user killed my Service ?

Comment: U should do nothing because the user doesn't want your service to run...in your app you can show a warning that killing service will disable features

Comment: when user closed the app, service will be stopped too and android wont start it again. but that doesn't necessary means that user doesn't want my service to run

Comment: The service should restart by itself...If it's not restarting their might be problem in firmware .